# go fmt.Scan into Array

Tags: go, stdin

The `fmt` package has a Scan function that reads stdin, and writes consecutive space separated values to the variables you provide. Is there a way to use this with Slices, so that I could create a slice of sice n, and have scan read n values and put them into the slice?

Comment: You can use [bytes.Buffer](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) or [bytes.Reader](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Reader) for this purpose. These struct are specifically designed for the purpose you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your call to `fmt.Scan` in a `for` loop.

Comment: Apparently this can be slow, since `fmt.Scan` doesn't use buffering. I've seen `fmt.Fscan + bufio.Reader(os.Stdin)` suggested instead.